# R change vector to pythonic tuple

Tags: r

Hi I want to change a vector of strings into one string, which is in the Python Tuple format.

Input:

```
a <- c('stack', 'overflow', 'kicks', 'ass')
```

Expected Output:

```
"('stack', 'overflow', 'kicks', 'ass')"
```

What would be an easy solution to implement?

This is what I have done and I expect there should be an easier solution:

```
> b <- a[1]
> for(word in a[-1]){ b <- paste(b, word, sep="','") }
> b
[1] "stack','overflow','kick','ass"
> b <- paste("('", b, "')",sep="") 
> b
[1] "('stack','overflow','kick','ass')"
```

Comment: Avoid the loop and use `paste(a, collapse="','")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> paste0("(", paste(sQuote(a), collapse = ","), ")")
[1] "(‘stack’,‘overflow’,‘kicks’,‘ass’)"
> options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
> paste0("(", paste(sQuote(a), collapse = ","), ")")
[1] "('stack','overflow','kicks','ass')"
>  substring(capture.output(dput(a)), 2)
[1] "(\"stack\", \"overflow\", \"kicks\", \"ass\")"
```